# How to integrate FCM in android app built with MVVM?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-architecture-components

I have an android app built with MVVM design pattern with the use of `ViewModel` and `LiveData` by Google.

Now I want to integrate FCM in the app.

So, how will the FCM service will communicate with the different app components ? Should it directly communicate with the **data (model)** layer ? Should it be in `notifications` packages in `ui` package with different android view components like `NotificationsActivity` and `NotificationsAdapter` ?

Comment: Thanks @farhana. I've searched alot and didn't get what I need